# Continuous probability understandings

Tags: probability, statistics

We say that the probability of any exact value is zero when dealing with continuous probability. However, assuming this is the case, how does any continuous variable even exist? I understand, there are infinite possible outcomes, so doesn't continuous probability suggest that summing these infinite number of exact values, that all have probabilities of 0 eventually equal 1? This does not seem right.

Comment: Imagine any continuous case - for example, water in a glass. A full glass is $1$, an empty one is $0$. Can the glass be filled with any number between $0$ and $1$? Same with length and so on.

Comment: The rules of probability allow you to meaningfully add up a finite or countably infinite number of probabilities of disjoint events, but not an uncountably infinite number.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to think of it is it's physical counterpart.
when dealing with for example finitely many particle with mass $m_i$, when you put all this particles in a bag you say the mass of bag is $\Sigma m_i$, but when dealing with say a rod, the way you should think of it isn't that it is made by an uncountably many particles each of mass zero. The way to describe it's mass is to consider it's density function, and you can understand mass of different subsets(for example intervals) of it by integrating it's density over that subset.(integral being continuous counterpart of sum)
For the second part of your question where you say that summing over all points concludes that the whole probability equals zero, note that you are summing over an uncountable set which is not possible.